# How can I create functions for buttons made in PHP loop?

Tags: php

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
if(($record['Opponent'] == "") && ($record['better_name'] != $_SESSION['user_name'])){

    $acceptID = "accept" . $record['bet_ID'];
    echo "<form action=index.php method=post>";
    echo "<input type=submit name=" . $acceptID . " value="ACCEPT">"; 
    echo "<input type=hidden id=" . $record['bet_ID'] . ">"; 
    echo "</form>";
} elseif (($record['Opponent'] == "") && ($record['better_name'] == $_SESSION['user_name'])){
    echo "<form action=index.php method=post>";
    echo "<input type=submit name=delete value=DELETE>";
    echo "<input type=hidden id=" . $record['bet_ID'] . ">"; 
    echo "</form>";
} else {
    echo "Game Locked.";
```

Comment: not clear, you want form to be repeated too ? and what issue are you facing ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*functions for buttons*", exactly? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to tell us what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to pass bet_ID's via `$_POST['ACCEPT']` and `$_POST['DELETE']` commands. Turns out I didn't need forms for each input/button.  This is what worked for me:

```
## $record['bet_ID'] was pulled from an SQL database table.


echo "<input type=hidden name=accept value='$record[bet_ID]'>";
echo "<input type=submit value=Accept>";

$date = $_POST['accept'];
echo $date;
```